# How to create a row in a mysql trigger to satisfy a FK constraint

Tags: mysql

Within my database there are two tables, let's say `object` and `object_score`. An `object` has an `object_score_id` and that column is foreign keyed to `object_score.id`. We have the relation set up this way because, intuitively, an `object` owns its score.

The problem we're running into is that we'd like to write a trigger to automatically create a corresponding `object_score` when an `object` is inserted. However, we don't have any identifying information about an `object_score` to uniquely identify it, so if we create the row in a `BEFORE INSERT ON` trigger we have no way to add its `id` to the foreign key column in `object`.

Is there any way to work around this other than to flip the relationship so an `object_score` owns an `object`?

Comment: If you do not have any information about an object_score, why the need to create the record? Is there a reason an object cannot exist without a score? If not, why not create the object_score record first, then link the object to that object_score.

Comment: In thinking about it, adding object_id to object_score seems to make more sense, instead of having object_score_id in object. So an object score cannot exist without a valid object. Assuming object_scores are not re-used across objects.

Comment: You required trigger condition depends on the link direction and which table the trigger is on. A `BEFORE` trigger on the `object` table can be used to create an `object_score` and set it's `id` in the `object_score_id `. An `AFTER` trigger on the `object_score` table can create an `object` with the correct `object_score_id`.

Comment: The direction of the link depends on which way the 1:n relation is going.

Comment: @JRD I was trying to avoid that, but the more I think about it that seems like the right way to go. If you post that as an answer I can give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in a parent-child relationship, the foreign key would exist in the child table. In this case, object being the parent, and object_score being the child. So all object_scores are tagged (owned) with a object_id from object. Then, you can enforce that all object_scores have an object, and there are no orphans.

Having a foreign key in the parent table usually represents a look-up table, where you have an attribute that may be shared across rows. For example, object_color, and the object has a color_id.